# The Irreducibility of the Algebraic Set of a Sphere Over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, spheres, real-algebraic-geometry

I've been trying to show that the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ is irreducible as an algebraic set over $\mathbb{R}$. By this I mean that it cannot be written as the union of two proper algebraic subsets.

It is not enough that the polynomial is irreducible (as shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1124541) for example), and we can't use tools such as the Nullstellensatz since $\mathbb{R}$ is not algebraically closed.

Maybe we can use the fact that it is a manifold, or that it is connected. I might be missing something obvious, but I haven't been able to make any progress.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The answer you link already tells you what to do: if you can compute $I(V(x^2+y^2+z^2=1))$ (the *real radical* of $(x^2+y^2+z^2=1)$) and show that's prime, you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s smooth and connected. This is sufficient over any field.

Comment: What does "smooth" mean over a field other than $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$?

Comment: For varieties in $\mathbb{A} ^n$ it means the rank of the Jacobian is equal to the dimension at every point. In this case the Jacobian has rank one at each (maximal) point.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.